# Passing potential nulls to Macros in Spark view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I have the following macro:

```
<macro name="InputField" id="string" value="string">
...
      <input type="text" id="${id}" name="${id}" value="${value}  />
...
</macro>
```

And the call to the macro:

```
${InputField( "model.address.address1", 75, "Address", model.Address.Address1 )}
```

The only problem is that model.Address will be null in some situations
(creating the item instead of editing it), because of this the macro
doesn't run or fails and just outputs the macro call to the view.

How can I pass either "" or the value of model.Address.Address1
depending if Address is null or not? the null operator ($!{}) doesnt
seem to work in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1. Write method

```
public static string HandleNull(Func<object> func)
{
   try { return func().ToString(); } 
   catch (NullReferenceException) { return ""; }
}
```

and use it instead of Spark macro.

```
${InputField( "model.address.address1", 75, "Address", HandleNull(() => model.Address.Address1) )}
```

Solution 2. Use http://www.jmill.net/taxonomy/term/312

Solution 3.

```
<macro name="InputField" id="string" value="Func<string>">
...
      <input type="text" id="${id}" name="${id}" value="$!{value()}  />
...
</macro>

${InputField( "model.address.address1", 75, "Address", () => model.Address.Address1 )}
```

All the solutions depend on deferred execution.